# Error running a javascript code(Discord music bot) - OPUS_ENGINE_MISSING

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to run a simple discord bot just to play a music, the bot is connectin to the channel perfectly but when it tries to play the music I recive this error:

```
(node:3028) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: OPUS_ENGINE_MISSING
```

My code:

```
var servers = {};

function play(connection, message) {
    var server = servers[message.guild.id];

    server.dispatcher = connection.playStream(YTDL(server.queue[0], {filter: "audioonly"}));

    server.queue.shift();

    server.dispatch.on("end", function() {
        if(server.queue[0]) play(connection, message);
        else connection.disconnect();
    });
}

if(command === `${botSettings.prefix}play`)
{
    if(!args[0]) {
        message.channel.send("Please provide me a link!");
        return;
    }
    if(!message.member.voiceChannel) {
        message.channel.send("You must be in a voice channel!");
        return;
    }
    if(!servers[message.guild.id]) servers[message.guild.id] = {
        queue: []
    };

    var server = servers[message.guild.id];
    server.queue.push(args[0]);
    if(!message.guild.voiceConnection) message.member.voiceChannel.join().then(function(connection) {
        play(connection, message);
    });
}
```

Comment: I apologise if this is a stupid question but have you the opus engine installed? check npm also check out here where someone had the (same issue)[https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/issues/872]

Comment: I'm so stupid, I installed the opus on another bot and not on that one!

Comment: @S4muRaY can you close this question by replying to it with the solution and accepting your own answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can install [opusscript](https://www.npmjs.com/package/opusscript) like this:

> `npm i opusscript`

But I hear discord prefers [node-opus](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-opus)

> `npm i node-opus`

Hope this helps